# Заливка мозаикой фона

Tags: android

Необходимо фоны вьюшек заливать текстурками. Иногда менять текстурки динамически.
Заливку делаю так (bg1.xml):

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/texture1"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

устанавливаю фон так:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(condition ? R.drawable.bg1 : R.drawable.bg2);
```

Все замечательно подменяется, кроме одного момента: Текстура растягивается по вью, а не мостится мозаикой. Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ найден. При добавлении в layout, для каждого нового view, необходимо каждый раз делать копию bg1.xml и уже ее крепить. При программном варианте необходимо для каждого раза генерить новый Drawable:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmap = (BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.texture1);
bitmap.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmap);
```